# Selenium Webdriver sessionId or check if all browser windows are closed

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Is there a way to see if all the browser windows are closed?  I see that if you call driver.quit() or driver.close() on the WebDriver, the sessionId becomes null.  Is there a way to check that?

I don't want to make a call to a closed or quit driver as it throws a WebDriverException.  So I want to check to see the state of the browser before continuing on.

Comment: Invoking quit() on WebDriver closes all open windows opened by the driver. So what do you want to check? What do you mean by "state of the browser"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set

```
driver=null;
```

everytime you quit the browser and than check

```
if (browser!=null){
  //Attention: this comand is not supported
  //as far as i know ;)
  driver.doSomething();
}
```

or

```
try{


}catch (NullPointerException e)

    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.print"DAMN";
}
```

or receive a NullPointerException ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool InstanceExist
    {
        get
        {
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    return (Instance.WindowHandles != null); // allways returns true if browser instance exist or thrown error
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                    // means that browser was closed by user
                }
            }
            return false; // means that it wasn't created yet or was closed by developer programmally
        }
    }
```

You need to check 3 situations:

1. driver wasnt created
2. driver was closed by developer
3. browser was closed by user, but driwer instance still exists

All of those situations is checked with this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way to detect if all windows are closed is smth like:

```
boolean allWindowsClosed = webDriver.getWindowHandles().isEmpty();
```

getWindowHandles returns a set of window handles for all open windows - see http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getWindowHandles()

Answer (score 1):

Actually calling getWindowHandles while the browser windows is gone will raise an "UnreachableBrowserException".

You have to put the call into a try-catch block and handle that error. Actually that is the only known WORKING workournd for catching unexpected browser windows closes. I have a static method in a config class doing my driver handling: I restart my browser like this:

```
protected static void loadPages() {

    if (driver == null || driver.toString().contains("null"))  { //null refers to an missing session id

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //load all my page objects like
        loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
        //....
        //....

        }
try {
        if (driver.getWindowHandles() == null || driver.getWindowHandles().isEmpty()){ //will cause an UnreachableBrowserException if the browser really is not avalable. 
            try { //you actually dont need this try catch block 
                driver.quit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Quitting levtover driver did not work.");
            }
            driver = null; //you have to set the driver to null
            loadPages();
            }
    } catch (UnreachableBrowserException ube) {
        driver = null; //like above set to null to make sure no driver left
    }
```

}

Now, ofc your current test will fail but you will be able to go on with the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

in C#

```
    public void BrowserCheck()
    {
        try
        {
            var h = webDriver.WindowHandles;
            return; // no problem
        }
        catch // browser window is closed so re-init it
        {
            webDriver.Quit();
            WebDriverInit(); // your init code 
        }
    }
```