# Python Selenium: How to check whether the WebDriver did quit()?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to control whether my `WebDriver` quit but I can't find a method for that. ([It seems that in Java there's a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622590/1707938))

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.quit()
driver # <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x108424850>
driver is None # False
```

I also explored the attributes of `WebDriver` but I can't locate any specific method to get information on the driver status. Also checking the session id:

```
driver.session_id # u'7c171019-b24d-5a4d-84ef-9612856af71b'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you would explore the source code of the python-selenium driver, you would see what the [`quit()` method](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#64) of the firefox driver is doing:

```
def quit(self):
    """Quits the driver and close every associated window."""
    try:
        RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
    except (http_client.BadStatusLine, socket.error):
        # Happens if Firefox shutsdown before we've read the response from
        # the socket.
        pass
    self.binary.kill()
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path)
        if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
            shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

There are things you can rely on here: checking for the `profile.path` to exist or checking the [`binary.process`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py#73) status. It could work, but you can also see that there are only "external calls" and there is *nothing changing on the python-side* that would help you indicate that `quit()` was called.

In other words, you need to make an external call to check the *status*:

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command
>>> driver.execute(Command.STATUS)
{u'status': 0, u'name': u'getStatus', u'value': {u'os': {u'version': u'unknown', u'arch': u'x86_64', u'name': u'Darwin'}, u'build': {u'time': u'unknown', u'version': u'unknown', u'revision': u'unknown'}}}
>>> driver.quit()
>>> driver.execute(Command.STATUS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

You can put it under the `try/except` and make a reusable function:

```
import httplib
import socket

from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command

def get_status(driver):
    try:
        driver.execute(Command.STATUS)
        return "Alive"
    except (socket.error, httplib.CannotSendRequest):
        return "Dead"
```

Usage:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> get_status(driver)
'Alive'
>>> driver.quit()
>>> get_status(driver)
'Dead'
```

---

Another approach would be to *make your custom Firefox webdriver* and set the `session_id` to `None` in `quit()`:

```
class MyFirefox(webdriver.Firefox):
    def quit(self):
        webdriver.Firefox.quit(self)
        self.session_id = None
```

Then, you can simply check the `session_id` value:

```
>>> driver = MyFirefox()
>>> print driver.session_id
u'69fe0923-0ba1-ee46-8293-2f849c932f43'
>>> driver.quit()
>>> print driver.session_id
None
```

Comment: Is checking for driver termination necessary in "production quality" code? In other words, how do I balance really bullet proof code versus the time it takes to run all these checks?

Comment: @franklin I've actually never done browser termination checks while using selenium myself and I think the OP just had a specific use case here. Not sure if this is really needed to run after quitting the driver. What do you think?

Comment: I was so interested, I actually [asked the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426824/optimal-amount-of-testing-for-selenium/) here. I honestly think that the failure rate of deconstructing an object in _any_ language is so low that it isn't necessary to test.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem and tried returning the title - this worked for me using chromedriver...

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    driver.title
    print(True)
except WebDriverException:
    print(False)
```

Comment: If you are using this to determine if a driver is still "alive", it will only work if you have already loaded a website. A new driver would be ready to accept commands, but still print False here.

Answer (score 8):

This work for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print( driver.service.is_connectable()) # print True

driver.quit()
print( driver.service.is_connectable()) # print False
```

Comment: This simple solution still works well on **2023-4-17**. Other answers below this question were more or less outdated or getting to complicated. By the way, driver.service.is_connectable() is synchronized.

Comment: Works perfectly when you do `driver.quit()`. But i was kinda surprised that it still shows `True` after I do `driver.close()` for a single browser tab, so no running Chrome processes left.  Hmm, how it's `connectable` if browser in not running? Tried this on Ubuntu 22.04 Server.

Comment: I think the behaviour you mantioned is because the difference between the methods `close()` and `quit()`. While `close()` closes window/tab without ending session, `quit()` ends WebDriver session

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-driver-dispose-driver-close-and-driver-quit/)

Answer (score 2):

How about executing a driver command and checking for an exception:

```
import httplib, socket

try:
    driver.quit()
except httplib.CannotSendRequest:
    print "Driver did not terminate"
except socket.error:
    print "Driver did not terminate"
else:
    print "Driver terminated"
```

Answer (score 2):

suggested methods above didn't work for me on selenium version 3.141.0

```
dir(driver.service) found a few useful options 

driver.session_id   
driver.service.process
driver.service.assert_process_still_running()
driver.service.assert_process_still_running
```

I found this SO question when I had a problem with closing an already closed driver, in my case a try catch around the driver.close() worked for my purposes.

```
try:
    driver.close()
    print("driver successfully closed.")
except Exception as e:
    print("driver already closed.")
```

also:

```
import selenium
help(selenium)
```

to check selenium version number

Answer (score 0):

it works in java, checked on FF

```
((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getSessionId() == null
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this function:

> if driver.service.isconnectible():
> print('Good to go')

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to detect whether the browser interface was closed - regardless - chromedriver's status. As such, none of the answers here worked, and I just decided to go for the obvious:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    driver.current_url
    print('Selenium is running')
except WebDriverException:
    print('Selenium was closed')
```

Even though it's a bit of a hack, it's served my purposes perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

''''python
def closedriver():
global drivername
drivername.quit()
global driveron
driveron=False
''''
this function "closedriver"  uses a global variable named "drivername" and global bool variable named "driveron",you may just pass a current driver as parameter but
NOTE: driveron must be global to store the state of driver being 'on' or 'off'.
''''python
def closedriver(drivername):
global driveron
try:
drivername.quit()
except:
pass
driveron=False
''''
and when you start a new driver, just use a check
global driveron
if not driveron:
driver=webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65265545/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please try to always include some explanation about your solution. This help others understand your approach.

Comment: This approach does not really answer the OP's question. Also, it appears you are using a global variable `drivername` to share the driver among parts of your code and a second global variable `driveron` to share the status of the latter. This is not necessary. As you can see from the other replys, you can just query the status of your driver directly by querying `drivername`.