# Chrome browser closes immediately after loading from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am running a basic python program to open the Chrome Window but as soon as the code executes, the window is there for a sec and then it closes immediately.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\APIR\chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Chromedriver version: 91.0.4472.101
Chrome Version: 91.0.4472.164

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If this is your entire program than this is expected, add a breakpoint after the navigation to stop the script. If you have an error, post it with the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Guy : that is not expected, there is no way driver is going to kill chrome instance with the above code.

Comment: @cruisepandey It does in Python, this is how the language work.

Comment: @Guy  :No it does not, I checked it right after your comment, and the window still stand solid.

Answer (score 4):

It closes because the program ends.
You can:

Wait with `time.sleep`, for example `time.sleep(10)` to keep the browser open for 10 seconds after everything is done

Have the user press enter with `input()`

Or detect when the browser is closed. Many ways to do that.
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52000037/8997916

You could also catch the BrowserUnreachable exception in a loop with a small delay

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try using the sleep method earlier but I had seen that in a couple of videos browser used to stay open hence I thought there was something wrong with the program. Detecting when the browser is closed seems like a good option.

Answer (score 2):

For Edge Browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options, service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543285/chrome-browser-closes-immediately-after-loading-from-selenium')
```

For Chrome Browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service('./path/to/chromedriver'))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543285/chrome-browser-closes-immediately-after-loading-from-selenium')
```